# dynamically loading in pictures from database

Tags: javascript

i'd want to make divs with javascript and load in pictures to these seperate divs
i however get append child is undefined

the phpfile works properly

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open('GET' , url.com/phpfile, false);
request.send();

if(request.status == 0)
    console.log(request.responseText);

var picture;
var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
console.log(obj);
for (var i= 0 ;  i<obj.length; i++){
var div = document.createElement("target");
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.id= ('target'+i);
picture = obj[i].LastPicture;
img.src=picture;
document.getElementById(div).appendChild(img)
console.log(picture);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your relevant html? Also, I think there are some syntax issues (url, xmlhttprequest() ).

Comment: You're Missing `request.onreadystatechange=function(){...}` btw what is the responseText you're getting? Try Logging or alerting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something like this:

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "path_to_img";
document.getElementById("some_id_from_body").appendChild(img);
```

You need have in mind that document.createElement('target'); does not add your newly created element to document.

In your sample, document.body.appendChild('div'), i think it should be document.body.appendChild(div);, without quotes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there a a number of issues:

1. You don't wait until the response is back;
2. You can't set the src of a div to a byte array (btw, you are calling `==`, while you probably meant `=`);
3. Your call `appendChild` on the `body`, not on the `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$("<img src='"+obj[i].picture+"'></img>").appendTo("#"+target+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

> [..] i however get append child is undefined.

That's because you cannot pass a string to the bodies `.appendChild()` function. You could create a div-element by using `document.createElement('div')` and pass this to the `.appendChild()`.